# result of selection formula must be a boolean

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

Using VB.Net

Store Procedure like this

```
@Orderno nvarchar(1000)

Select * from table1 where id = ''+@orderno+''
```

In VB.Net code

```
Dim value as string
Value = "1"
    objForm.ViewReport(myReportPath & "rOrder.rpt", "value") `' Showing error on this line`
```

I tried with `'"& value &"', "value"`, same error

I tried with  "" & value & ""  showing error as `the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula`

How to pass the string properly to store procedure

Need Vb.Net Code Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is really not clear, and I see no call to stored procedures, but if you want to pass a variable by parameter, just drop the quotes:

```
Dim value as string = "1"
objForm.ViewReport(myReportPath & "rOrder.rpt", value)
```

Comment: Tried, Showing error as  the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula

Comment: What is the ViewReport method? Do you have access to the code or documentation for that method?

Comment: View report is a sub procedure, there is checking the parameter values, can y give some other code or method to do. I want to run the report through store procedure by passing the parameter values.  Can you help me...